# T-SQL Trigger INSERT UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, procedure

I'm fairly new in T-SQL but i have a question concerning triggers. I have written a trigger that is used in my stored procedure witch inserts and updates data.

Now the trigger works when any row is updated in table `[dbo].[users]`

I don't know how to modify this trigger so that if data is inserted into `[dbo].[users]` table activate the trigger (this works now), but how to acheive an update scenario on the same trigger that if only a specific row is UPDATED in `[dbo].[users]` table that only then the trigger should be activated.

For example

1. If a new user is inserted and all rows are inserted in this table - activate trigger
2. If an old trigger is updated but only a specific field in this table is updated (working_state is the name of a  column) then only should the trigger should be activated.

Source code what I have is shown here:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[t_temp_triger_name] 
ON [dbo].[users] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @working_state char(1),
            @user_code char(11)

    DECLARE zm CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            working_state,
            user_code
        FROM
            inserted
-- Added update statement that activates the trigger only when a specific -
-- column update is executed 
UPDATE  [dbo].[users]
SET working_state = 1
FROM  [dbo].[users] U 
INNER JOIN DELETED D ON U.user_code= D.user_code
WHERE U.working_state<> D.working_state


    OPEN zm

    FETCH NEXT FROM zm INTO @working_state, @user_code

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [FNF].[dbo].[NamedProcedure] 
                @working_state, @user_code

        FETCH NEXT FROM zm INTO @working_state, @user_code
    END

    CLOSE zm
    DEALLOCATE zm   
END
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this only using 1 trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with a solution

Added this to my code after declaration

Everything works fine.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)

BEGIN 
    DECLARE zm CURSOR FOR
SELECT

    u.working_state,
    u.user_code
FROM
    inserted U 
LEFT JOIN DELETED D ON U.user_code= D.user_code
WHERE U.working_state<> D.working_state
END
    ELSE 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE zm CURSOR FOR
SELECT

    working_state,
    user_code
FROM
    inserted
END
```